# How to convert webrtc::VideoFrame to OpenCv Mat in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, webrtc

I am trying to display received WebRTC frames using OpenCV `imshow()`. WebRTC delivers frames as objects of `webrtc::VideoFrame` and in my case, I can access `webrtc::I420Buffer` from it. Now my question is how do I convert the data in `webrtc::I420Buffer` to `cv::Mat`, so that I can give it to `imshow()`?

Thsi is what the definition of `webrtc::I420Buffer` looks like

```
namespace webrtc {

// Plain I420 buffer in standard memory.
class RTC_EXPORT I420Buffer : public I420BufferInterface {
 public:
  ...

  int width() const override;
  int height() const override;
  const uint8_t* DataY() const override;
  const uint8_t* DataU() const override;
  const uint8_t* DataV() const override;

  int StrideY() const override;
  int StrideU() const override;
  int StrideV() const override;

  uint8_t* MutableDataY();
  uint8_t* MutableDataU();
  uint8_t* MutableDataV();

  ...

 private:
  const int width_;
  const int height_;
  const int stride_y_;
  const int stride_u_;
  const int stride_v_;
  const std::unique_ptr<uint8_t, AlignedFreeDeleter> data_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is converting from I420 color format to BGR (or BGRA) color format used by OpenCV.

Two good options for color conversion:

- Using `sws_scale` - part of the C interface libraries of [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__libsws.html).
- Using IPP color conversion function like [ippiYCbCr420ToBGR_709HDTV_8u_P3C4R](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-2-image-processing/image-color-conversion/color-model-conversion/ycbcr420tobgr-709hdtv.html).

We may also use [cv::cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/db/d64/tutorial_js_colorspaces.html) with `cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420` argument.
This is less recommended, because the Y, U and V color channels must be sequential in memory - in the general case, it requires too many "deep copy" operations.

After the color conversion we may use cv:Mat constructor that "wraps" the BGR (or BGRA) memory buffer (without using "deep copy").

Example (the terms "step", "stride" and "linesize" are equivalent):

```
cv::Mat bgra_img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, pDst, dstStep);
```

---

Create sample raw image in I420 format for testing:
We may use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) CLI for creating the input file that is used for testing:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:duration=1:rate=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo I420.yuv
```

Note: FFmpeg `yuv420p` is equivalent to `I420` format.

---

The code sample includes two part:
The first part uses **sws_scale**, and the second part uses **IPP**.
Choose one of them (you don't have to use both).

For testing, I redefined and added some functionality to `class I420Buffer`.
It may look weird, but it is used only for testing.
Just follow the code sample, and see that it makes sense...

---

Here is the code sample (please read the comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Use OpenCV for showing the image
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


extern "C" {
//Required for using sws_scale
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

//We don't need both IPP and LibAV, the IPP solution is a separate example.
#include <ipp.h>
#include <ippi.h>



//I420 format:
//            <------ stride_y_------>
//            <------- width ------>
// data_y_ -> yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy00
//            yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy00
//            yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy00
//            yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy00
//            yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy00
//            yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy00
//
//            < stride_u_>
//            <-width/2->
// data_u_ -> uuuuuuuuuuu0
//            uuuuuuuuuuu0
//            uuuuuuuuuuu0
//            
//            < stride_v_>
//            <-width/2->
// data_v_ -> uuuuuuuuuuu0
//            uuuuuuuuuuu0
//            uuuuuuuuuuu0

 


// Plain I420 buffer in standard memory.
// Some extra functionality is added for testing
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class I420Buffer {
    public:
        //Constructor (for testing):
        //Allocate buffers, and read I420 image for binary file.
        explicit I420Buffer(int w, int h, const char *input_file_name) : width_(w), height_(h), stride_y_(w), stride_u_(w / 2), stride_v_(w / 2) 
        {
            //The example uses stride = width (but in the general case the stride may be larger than width).
            data_y_ = new uint8_t[w*h];
            data_u_ = new uint8_t[w*h / 4];
            data_v_ = new uint8_t[w*h / 4];

            FILE* f = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");
            fread(data_y_, 1, w*h, f);  //Read Y color channel.
            fread(data_u_, 1, w*h/4, f);  //Read U color channel.
            fread(data_v_, 1, w*h/4, f);  //Read V color channel.
            fclose(f);
        };

        //Destructor (for testing):
        ~I420Buffer()
        {
            delete[] data_y_;
            delete[] data_u_;
            delete[] data_v_;
        }

        int width() const { return width_; };
        int height() const { return height_; };
        const uint8_t* DataY() const { return data_y_; };
        const uint8_t* DataU() const { return data_u_; };
        const uint8_t* DataV() const { return data_v_; };

        int StrideY() const { return stride_y_; };
        int StrideU() const { return stride_u_; };
        int StrideV() const { return stride_v_; };

        //uint8_t* MutableDataY();
        //uint8_t* MutableDataU();
        //uint8_t* MutableDataV();

    private:
        const int width_;
        const int height_;
        const int stride_y_;
        const int stride_u_;
        const int stride_v_;
        //const std::unique_ptr<uint8_t, AlignedFreeDeleter> data_;
        uint8_t* data_y_;   //Assume data_ is internally divided into Y, U and V buffers.
        uint8_t* data_u_;
        uint8_t* data_v_;
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



int main()
{
    //Create raw video frame in I420 format using FFmpeg (for testing):
    //ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:duration=1:rate=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo I420.yuv
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    I420Buffer I(width, height, "I420.yuv");


    //Create SWS Context for converting from decode pixel format (like YUV420) to BGR
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    struct SwsContext* sws_ctx = NULL;

    sws_ctx = sws_getContext(I.width(),
                             I.height(),
                             AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,  //Input format is yuv420p (equivalent to I420).
                             I.width(),
                             I.height(),
                             AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,    //For OpenCV, we want BGR pixel format.
                             SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             NULL);

    if (sws_ctx == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;  //Error!
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Allocate frame for storing image converted to BGR.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    AVFrame* pBGRFrame = av_frame_alloc();  //Allocate frame, because it is more continent than allocating and initializing data buffer and linesize.

    pBGRFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;
    pBGRFrame->width = I.width();
    pBGRFrame->height = I.height();

    int sts = av_frame_get_buffer(pBGRFrame, 0);    //Buffers allocation

    if (sts < 0)
    {
        return -1;  //Error!
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Convert from input format (e.g YUV420) to BGR:
    //Use BT.601 conversion formula. It is more likely that the input is BT.709 and not BT.601 (read about it in Wikipedia).
    //It is possible to select BT.709 using sws_setColorspaceDetails
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const uint8_t* const src_data[] = { I.DataY(), I.DataU(), I.DataV() };
    const int src_stride[] = { I.StrideY(), I.StrideU(), I.StrideV() };

    sts = sws_scale(sws_ctx,                //struct SwsContext* c,
                    src_data,               //const uint8_t* const srcSlice[],
                    src_stride,             //const int srcStride[],
                    0,                      //int srcSliceY, 
                    I.height(),             //int srcSliceH,
                    pBGRFrame->data,        //uint8_t* const dst[], 
                    pBGRFrame->linesize);   //const int dstStride[]);

    if (sts != I.height())
    {
        return -1;  //Error!
    }


    //Use OpenCV for showing the image (and save the image in JPEG format):
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(pBGRFrame->height, pBGRFrame->width, CV_8UC3, pBGRFrame->data[0], pBGRFrame->linesize[0]);    //cv::Mat is OpenCV "thin image wrapper".
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    //cv::waitKey();

    //Save the inage in PNG format using OpenCV
    cv::imwrite("rgb.png", img);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Free
    sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&pBGRFrame);



    // Solution using IPP:
    // The IPP sample use BT.709 conversion formula, and convert to BGRA (not BGR)
    // It is more likely that the input is BT.709 and not BT.601 (read about it in Wikipedia).
    // Using color conversion function: ippiYCbCr420ToBGR_709HDTV_8u_P3C4R
    //https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-2-image-processing/image-color-conversion/color-model-conversion/ycbcr420tobgr-709hdtv.html
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    IppStatus ipp_sts = ippInit();

    if (ipp_sts < ippStsNoErr)
    {
        return -1;  //Error.
    }

    const Ipp8u* pSrc[3] = { I.DataY(), I.DataU(), I.DataV() };
    int srcStep[3] = { I.StrideY(), I.StrideU(), I.StrideV() };
    Ipp8u* pDst = new uint8_t[I.width() * I.height() * 4];
    int dstStep = I.width() * 4;
    IppiSize roiSize = { I.width(), I.height() };

    ipp_sts = ippiYCbCr420ToBGR_709HDTV_8u_P3C4R(pSrc,      //const Ipp8u* pSrc[3], 
                                                 srcStep,   //int srcStep[3], 
                                                 pDst,      //Ipp8u* pDst, 
                                                 dstStep,   //int dstStep, 
                                                 roiSize,   //IppiSize roiSize, 
                                                 255);      //Ipp8u aval)

    if (ipp_sts < ippStsNoErr)
    {
        return -1;  //Error.
    }

    cv::Mat bgra_img = cv::Mat(I.height(), I.width(), CV_8UC4, pDst, dstStep);    //cv::Mat is OpenCV "thin image wrapper".
    cv::imshow("bgra_img", bgra_img);
    cv::waitKey();

    delete[] pDst;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

---

Sample output (resized):
[image]

---

Note:
It seems to difficult to actually use WebRTC input stream.
The assumption is that the decoded raw video frame already exists in `I420Buffer` as defined in your post.